# Biber and Biblatex compatibility error after updating all of the packages using MikTex Package manager on Windows 10

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am trying to use biblatex and biber on texmaker. I updated all of the packages as per the post here: [How to fix the incompatility between BiBer and BiBLaTeX versions in TeXmaker?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309991/how-to-fix-the-incompatility-between-biber-and-biblatex-versions-in-texmaker) but I still get the following error

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.12 INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg' INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.5. This means that your biber (2.12) and biblatex (3.11) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation. INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

I am a bit puzzled because MikTex Package manager shows that my biblatex version is 3.12 and my biber is 2.12 but the error message states that my biblatex control file version is 3.4! I'm not sure what that means.

I did update package database in MikTex after updating all of the packages.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check for update as user **and** as admin?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer admin

Comment: Then check also in user mode.

Comment: There maybe an old `bcf` file from a previous run. Delete all helper files of your project, except of the `.tex` file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer checked in used mode. It worked! Thank you