# . This means that your biber (2.12) and biblatex (3.13a) versions are incompatible. See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentat

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber, incompatibility

INFO - This is Biber 2.12 INFO - Logfile is 't01_txt.blg' INFO - Reading 't01_txt.bcf' ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.6, expected version 3.5. This means that your biber (2.12) and biblatex (3.13a) versions are incompatible. See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation. INFO - ERRORS: 1

HOw can i solve this problem. I am using TexMaker.

Comment: You need to update your tex installation. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/15925

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to fix the incompatility between BiBer and BiBLaTeX versions in TeXmaker?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309991/134144)

Comment: Make sure your system is fully updated. If you are using MikTeX on a multi-user installation, that means that you need to run the Update in Admin and User mode. In any case, this issue can be caused by outdated temporary files. So if you are lucky you can resolve the issue by deleting the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` files and rerunning LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX.

Comment: Any news here? At the moment this question is more or less a duplicate of the 'how do I properly update my TeX distribution' question, but there could be more to it. Did removing the temporary files and making a full update help?