# Error Undefined Control Sequence: \Ginclude@graphics ... \Ginput@path

Tags: errors, miktex, includegraphics, undefined

I have this error message (seen below) for every graphic i included in my document. 
Backround: I use jabref for citation. because there were an incompability problem i followed the instructions from this [How to fix the incompatility between BiBer and BiBLaTeX versions in TeXmaker?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309991/how-to-fix-the-incompatility-between-biber-and-biblatex-versions-in-texmaker) . so i updated my miktex console packages. anyway since then i have a error when compiling. In the PDF the graphics are gone and just the data name is printed. Now i cannot compile anymore.

Sorry i am not an expert. thats why i give all this information. hope anybody can help me! 
If you need more information, please let me know!
Thanks a lot!

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file
{#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...
l.11 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{img/HOSTlogo}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10?

Comment: There was a temporary MikTeX mishap that should be resolved now. Update MikTeX in both Admin *and* User mode. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473/35864

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. wright and moewe!!! Works again :)